# Is there a way to make a relation when creating a node, on a certain condition? Cypher 3.5

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and graph databases.

I am looking for a way create a node while connecting it to another node matching that has a field that matches a certain parameter.

Here's a diagram to get the idea: 
[image: diagram of the situation]

Let's say my parameter is `:params {friendNodeId: 2}`

In my Cypher query, I would like to create my new node with its field `name: "my brand new node"`. Then if there is a node having `uniqueId = $params.friendNodeId` create a relation between this node and my new node.

My approach is to optimize the entire process by running a single query and not having to make an unnecessary match in a second query to get the newly created node.

If you think that it doesn't make sense at all don't hesitate to come up with another proposition.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This seems rather straight forward, what have you tried so far (in Cypher), and what about that result isn't working for you?

Comment: I did try ;-) the issue is that when the other node I am linking to doesn't exist, it ends up not creating my new node, which I don't want (relationship is optional, creation is mandatory)

Comment: `:params {"ids":[ {"id":1}, {"id":2}, {"id":3} ]}`

`UNWIND $ids AS id
CREATE (n:Node)
SET n.uId = id.id,
n.name = ("name " + id.id)`

`:params {"uniqueId":0`

`MATCH (other:Node {uId: $uniqueId})
CREATE (new:Node {uId: 4}),
(new)-[r:FRIEND]->(other)
SET new.name = "name 4"
RETURN r`

I get `(no changes, no records)`

But if my `$uniqueId` is part of an existing Node like `node 2` with `uId:2` so `:params {"uniqueId":2}` it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example in the comments, if the node creation is mandatory, but the relationship creation is optional (depending on if there is a node that matches), then you can just move the CREATE to before your MATCH:

```
CREATE (new:Node {uId: 4})
SET new.name = "name 4" 
WITH new
MATCH (other:Node {uId: $uniqueId})
CREATE (new)-[r:FRIEND]->(other) 
RETURN r
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine :-D thanks heaps for your help. So basically with what I can understand from your query and cypher's manual, `WITH` keyword helps me pass data from one part of a query to another, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, WITH is a means to pass on the variables you want to keep in scope (any others drop out of scope), and it's a good place to do aggregations and manipulation of data with function calls.